# Unable to enter Windows 10 boot loader from GRUB after 'installing' Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, bios

I succeed in updating grub menu to shows windows 10 boot loader. However, if I select windows to boot, the screen turn black and then turn into grub background color but frozen, so I'm unable to start windows.

I did encountered this before in my friend's machine, I fix it simply by disabling UEFI, then grub can boot windows normally but mine is different, I see no such options related to UEFI in BIOS settings.

I know how to restore/edit windows BCD, but since I use Ubuntu as my default OS, I don't want to press enter twice (windows boot menu --> grub --> ubuntu) every time I want to boot Ubuntu.

This is my `RESULTS.txt` after executing Boot Info Script:

- http://pastebin.com/7RP0LfKy (from [SourgeForge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/))
- <s>http://pastebin.com/7RP0LfKy (from [GitHub](https://github.com/arvidjaar/bootinfoscript))</s>
- http://pastebin.com/5egUjvjt (from GitHub)

Comment: Are both Windows & Ubuntu installed in same boot mode either both UEFI or both BIOS? And in Windows 10 have you turned off fast start up or the always on hibernation. Grub only boots working, not hibernated Windows. And can only boot systems installed in same boot mode. May be best to see details:
Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Comment: @oldfred I already disable windows hibernation, windows boot mode is BIOS, and I think grub is using UEFI. The problem is when I enter BIOS setup, I see no such option relates to UEFI/BIOS (unlike in my friend machine).

Comment: Please run the [Boot Info Script](https://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/). This will generate a file called `RESULTS.txt`. Post that file to [a pastebin site](http://paste.ubuntu.com) and post the URL to your document here. This will give us more details about your configuration, which is required to base an answer on more than guesswork.

Comment: @RodSmith I did, check it out

Comment: Looks like a standard setup for a Win 7 upgrade to Win 10 -- like I'm running.  Nothing seems obviously wrong.

Comment: @ubfan1 I installed Windows 10 directly (using iso file, not from win7) in my desktop computer, then I use ghost to clone Windows to my laptop (which currently contains Ubuntu), after a while, I install Ubuntu and has this problem.

Comment: What is this file?/NST/menu.lst That looks like a grub4dos or legacy grub menu. Are you using EasyBCD or something? That may give two menus by default. Also better to run Boot-Repair's summary report or newer fork of bootinfoscript at : https://github.com/arvidjaar/bootinfoscript

Comment: @oldfred I did used EasyBCD in Windows 10, but I think it doesn't cause the problem: my friend's machine encountered the same problem but he didn't use EasyBCD at all. And I'm pretty sure that Ubuntu installed grub2 on my machine, and EasyBCD still use legacy Windows boot menu (Windows 10 has a graphical boot menu but I switched to legacy boot menu)

Comment: @oldfred This is my `C:\NST\menu.lst`: http://pastebin.com/ZLnqbje2 (Created by EasyBCD)

Comment: @oldfred I executed [bootinfoscript](https://github.com/arvidjaar/bootinfoscript) as you said and add the link to the question

Comment: This UUID is the same on sda & sdb. D49A507B9A505C54  That is not allowed and leads to all sorts of issues. But not sure related to boot issue.

Comment: @oldfred sdb is my external drive - not always plugged-in, sda1 and sdb1 has the same UUID because I used Norton Ghost to clone my Windows, I'm pretty sure that is not the cause of the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just find a solution today, it isn't related to BIOS/UEFI but rather graphical/non-graphical user interface: Just disable GRUB2 graphical interface and it works.

**Step 1:** Edit file `/etc/default/grub` (as super-user), add (or uncomment) the following line

```
# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
GRUB_TERMINAL=console
```

**Step 2:** Update grub

```
sudo update-grub
```